# Missing required parameters: id actionView in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I made label -> Profil and set his url to /bloggers/view but when i log in and try to see the users profil it shows me an error.I made search around the network but did not realise how to solve the problem! Can you guys help me? Why is my actionView does not take the $id of the logged user(Blogger in my case)?

```
  public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }
```

I am registrating the user with this action:

```
public function actionRegister()
    {
        $model = new RegisterForm();
        $user = new Blogger();

        if(isset($_POST['register-button']))
        {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['RegisterForm'];

            if($model->validate())
            {
                $user->username = $model->username;
                $user->email = $model->email;

                $pass_hash = md5($model->password);

                $user->password = $pass_hash;
                $user->save();

                \Yii::$app->user->login($user);
                $this->redirect('index');

            }
        }

        return $this->render('register',[
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

I am still hard newbie and mayba i did stupid thnig in the code, but please forgive me!Thank you in advace!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actionView will take id parameter from url as per Yii format.

Ex:- domain.com/xxx?id=5 or domain.com/xxx/id/6

If you want to pass logged user id then you have to modify actionView like

```
public function actionView()
{
    $id = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id; // id should match with user table column
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Dude, realy.. you are my savior ! Thank you so much!